# How to remove the iteration path for a Team in TFS 2012/13

Tags: tfs

My question is simple:

Is it possible to remove an Iteration Path from TFS 2012/13 for a specific team?

The iterations path structure looks like this:

- RootPath

  - Development

    - Release X.X
    - ...
    - Release X.Y
    - ...
  - Ideas

I created different teams which had different default iterations.

Team 1: Default iteration = Development
Team 2: Default iteration = Ideas
Team 3: Default iteration = RootPath

Now: Team 2 should only be able to see the "RootPath" and "Ideas" iterations but not the "Development" iteration when they create a PBI in the product backlog.

Any idea how to do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible. You can secure the iteration paths so that people can't edit them, but you can't hide the visibility.

There's [a suggestion to change this](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2266453-hide-area-and-iteration-names-users-don-t-have-per) on the Visual Studio User Voice site that you can vote on.

While you can't hide them, you could prevent people from editing work items for iteration paths they don't have permission to. It involves customising the work item templates (you can't do this in VS Team Services) and it's probably much mork work than is worthwhile since you're embedding iteration paths into the work item template, but if you like pain then see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dstfs/archive/2010/04/14/tfs-2008-can-you-restrict-users-from-selecting-certain-iteration-paths.aspx) for an example of how you might do it.